# German Magazine Client not paying (US Freelance Illustrator)

Tags: payments

I've been doing work for a few years for a German Magazine. They have always paid late. Recently I started following up requesting they pay me what they owe me, wiring all late payments (currently over $8K). They are ghosting me. I emailed the publisher, accounting person and art director. What recourse do I have?

Answer (score 2):

As a US citizen or business you have practically **zero** ability to forcibly collect from an international client. You would have to use laws local to the client for any collection. *And*, adhere to any stipulations regarding foreign demands. It's nowhere near as simple as simply filing suit or hiring a collection agency.

You can try some international B2B collection agencies (simply Google that). They typically cost much more than local collection agencies, but that's probably your best shot.

Typical collection recourse offered in one's own country *never* travels/works across borders. Laws vary from country to country and a German business is not obligated to adhere to US laws regarding collection. The *best* you could hope for is some German law which you could possibly use to aide collection. For example, the UK has some decent laws regarding collection if you can prove the debt. I do not know if Germany has similar laws. This is where the international B2B collection agencies come it, being familiar with laws in various countries and what can or can't be used for collection.

This is a *major* reason I **always** demand payment up front from any international client.